# Fix OrigClOrdID (tag 41) in a chain of replaces. Is it the very first one of the order OR the previous one in the chain?

Tags: java, c++, quickfix, trading, fix-protocol

So whenever I want to change (reduce) the quantity of my order (*OrderCancelReplaceRequest*) I have to send a new ClOrdID and the original ClOrdID (tag 41). Ok, so let's say I change the quantity for a second time. Does the original ClOrdID (tag 41) I have to send now is the very first one or the previous one?

Answer (score 4):

It is the client order id after the modification (most current one before this cancel/replace request), not the original one. You can check this in [FIXimate](http://fixprotocol.org/FIXimate3.0/), where the description of the field says:

> ClOrdID (11) of the previous order (NOT the initial order of the day) as assigned by the institution, used to identify the previous order in cancel and cancel/replace requests.

Comment: Thanks, but "NOT the initial order of the day" does not make any sense. They should have said "NOT the initial order of the chain".

Answer (score 0):

It is clOrdId of the most recent one (the one sent last). Even if server queues the messages or it handles each one instantly, both ways it works. I think there are some scenarios in the Matrix somewhere (not sure probably in FIX site only), which indicate the same. Let me know if you need more explanation.